# Estos dos loops for pueden ejecutarse por separado?

Tags: optimización

En cuanto a velocidad de calculo, es lo mismo:

```
for(int a = 0; a<10; a++)
{
  var1[a] = random(255);
}

for(int b = 0; b<10; b++)
{
  var2[b] = random(255);
}
```

**a:**

```
for(int a = 0; a<10; a++)
{
  var1[a] = random(255);
  var2[a] = random(255);
}
```

Porque desde la ignorancia y mi sentido común, a pesar de ser dos ciclos (por ende, 20 busquedas en los arrays) en el primer caso, en el 2do se cambia de valor al doble de variables que en el primero.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu pregunta es si el runtime de ambas funciones es el mismo, la respuesta es Si. Y es **O(n)**.

En cuanto a runtime se refiere, es igual recorrer 2 arrays de longitud **n** en bucles separados (**2n**), que recorrer los mismos 2 arrays, siempre y cuando no estén anidados, dentro de un mismo bucle.

.